# How do I insert line breaks into a text file i'm creating on the SD Card?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

My code is pretty standard.. sReport contains the text I would like output to the text file, and it contains several "\n" line breaks that render fine in a textview, but in the text file they're non-existent. There must be something easy i'm missing..

```
    try {
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(sDir + sFile);
        //write  
        fOut.write( sReport.getBytes() );
        // Close output stream
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (IOException  e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: what are you using to view the text files on sdcard?

Comment: notepad.. i'm just looking to export a standard ascii stream, so maybe FileOutputStream isn't what I want?

Comment: It's not FileOutputStreamFaultm I'd say naikus is right, probably notepad on windows doesn't show the breaks correctly. Try adding \r just after \n.

Comment: That's correct. Notepad (or most windows apps in general) won't display it correctly because you'll need different linebreaks

Answer (score 0):

please review [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/01/the-great-newline-schism.html) and keep in mind Android is Linux based.